# Binary search algorithm - worst-case complexity

Tags: complexity-theory, recurrence-relation, binary-search

I tried to calculate the worst case of binary search (not binary search tree). My calculations:
$$T(n) = T\left(\frac{n}{2}\right) + 1$$
$$T(n) = T\left(\frac{n}{4}\right) + (1+1) = T\left(\frac{n}{8}\right) + (1+1+1) = {\dots} = T\left(\frac{n}{2^{k}}\right)+(1\cdot k) $$
$$T(n)=T(1) + (1\cdot k) = c_{1} + (1\cdot k) =  c_{1} + log_{2}n = c_{1}+\frac{log(n)}{log(2)} $$
Finally the complexity should be
$$O(log(n)) $$
Is this a good way to prove the worst case complexity of binary search algorithm? Make I mistakes?

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Let me direct you towards our 
[reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599)
which cover techniques that can be applied to solve your problem, in particular http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/2789/755.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A much better way is to use the master method :), check that out!

Comment: Here is a useful document when working on things like this: it includes the master method. https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.tug.org/texshowcase/cheat.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwiz4dWRwPLQAhUlIcAKHdTlBbUQFggaMAA&usg=AFQjCNFeZx9JevUGn2nkvYmv0N5J9mr8XQ&sig2=CetJqZOlZO0SB7N6go08KA

Comment: Thx. I will check this document. BTW. My solution is good?

Comment: This solution is okay

Answer (score 2):

That's a way to do it. Sometimes it's easier to go the other way round: What is the size of the largest array where binary search will locate an item or determine it's not there, using k comparisons? And it turns out that the largest array has size $2^k - 1$. And then you reverse this.

Understanding the master method is very useful if you have to pass a test that tests whether you understand the master method. But be prepared to have more practical problem where the only method that works is the "turn on your brain" method. A simple example is the Greatest Common Divisor algorithm.